# Handling states in react that are updated very frequently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webview, android-webview, setstate

I have made a carousel with a custom scrollbar for which I am using states to update the scroll percentage to show as follows:

```
const useScrollPercentage = ref => {
    const [clientWidth, setClientWidth] = React.useState(0);
    const [scrollWidth, setScrollWidth] = React.useState(0);
    const [scrollLeft, setScrollLeft] = React.useState(0);

    const updateValues = () => {
        const { clientWidth, scrollWidth, scrollLeft } = ref.current;
        setClientWidth(clientWidth);
        setScrollLeft(scrollLeft);
        setScrollWidth(scrollWidth);
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        requestAnimationFrame(updateValues);
        // updateValues();
        const element = ref.current;
        if (element) {
            element.addEventListener('scroll', updateValues);
            return () => element.removeEventListener('scroll', updateValues);
        }
    }, [ref.current]);

    const scrollPercentage = (100 * scrollLeft) / (scrollWidth - clientWidth);
    return isNaN(scrollPercentage) ? 0 : scrollPercentage;
};
```

Now this does gives the expected output but the scrollbar is quite janky in webview due to the asynchronous nature of setState and internal batching of state updates in React.

I tried scheduling state updates in requestAnimationFrame but it didn't made much difference either. How should the states that are updated very fast should be handled for optimised and efficient performance without any lag?

Comment: See if `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect` helps